# Can I add extra fields into Eureka dashboard?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have now configured my Eureka server and I can see all my micro-services there. But I have added extra key-value pairs, related to my micro-services, to the metadata-map of instances.

Is it possible to show these extra parameters in the Eureka dashboard?
To simply put it: 
is there some way that I can modify what I see on the Eureka dashboard other than the standard parameters and standard layout?